# Automatically loads css file which is not even linked

Tags: html, css, eclipse

When I run the HTML page in the browser, the changes in CSS file do not show any results and loads the unedited CSS file. Even if I remove the linked CSS file, it automatically loads that CSS file and runs on the browser.

`<link href="css/style-py.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />`

The problem is only when I run it in eclipse IDE. If I run the same code from Sublime, it works fine.

Comment: Add more relevant code, like your entire HTML page.

Comment: It is happening with all the pages I am trying to edit.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page by emptying the cache? On most browsers that's done with Shift-F5, it may be different in your IDE.

Comment: @FedericoS, yes, that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser sometimes stores your files in a cache in order to load the files quickly.

Try this:

```
CTRL + F5
```

to refresh invalidating the cache.

The fix is called "hard refresh". this works in most Windows and Linux browsers. In your case, it may be different. Find the right shortcut depending on your environment.